# What is the reason for receiving "It is not supported to change the behavior at runtime." error in SAPUI5 application

Tags: sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 application and when I press on items to visit the detail or object page it shows the following error message in the following part of the code

> It is not supported to change the behavior at runtime.

```
showObject: function(oItem) {
    var sObjectId = oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("Partner");
    this.getRouter().navTo("object", {
        objectId: encodeURIComponent(sObjectId)
    }, false);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that's where you're getting it? I've only seen that error when working with certain controls the [UploadCollection](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.UploadCollection) and trying to fire a method like `oUploadCollection.setUploadUrl("/url")` which is not supported at runtime.

Without setting a property and given the code above, the error doesn't make sense.

*A side note: without seeing where your `showObject` method is called, it's hard to say... but if showObject is called directly off the press event of the ListItem you need to call `getSource()` on the event object. Might be throwing an error there about `getBindingContext()` not being a function.

Comment: You are right. The source of error is from upload collection object. I exactly set the url as it is dynamic in my system.